# increment column value with an integer when it is a duplicate

Tags: duplication, qgis-variable, integer

I have a layer with around 1000 lines. Some Name are repeated several times and I wish to have every name unique. Thus I try in the field calculator to add an integer at the end of the name only when it is a duplicate, and of course I want to increment the integer value each time it is used.
As an example, in my layer I have in the Column 'Name':

```
Name_One
Name_One
Name_Two
Name_Two
Name_One
```

And I would like it to become

```
Name_One1
Name_One2
Name_Two1
Name_Two2
Name_One3
```

I tried first to identify the duplicate with the function

```
if(count("Name", "Name") = 1, 1, 0)
```

Then with the new column "uniqueness" that hold the value of the previous command I try

```
CASE
    WHEN 'uniqueness' = 0 THEN @a
    WHEN 'uniqueness' = 0 THEN @a = @a+1
    ELSE @a = 1
END
```

(@a is a project variable equal to 1)

But it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**QGIS 3.0/3.2**

(1) Use **Add autoincremental field** tool (in `Processing Toolbox | Vector table`) to create new incremental number field.

- Input layer: your layer
- Field name: any name (default value is `AUTO`)
- Start values at: `1`
- Group values by: select your column `Name`
- Advanced parameters - Sort expression: select `id`

(2) Put `Name` and `AUTO` fields together

Open the Field Calculator and create a new field by `concat("Name", "AUTO")`

[image]